$f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x-3}}$ and $g(1)=e$ which of the following options is/are correct?
Multiple Choice Question :

In a question, a student was given to find the derivative of the product of two functions $'f'$ and $'g'$.
The student by mistake thought $(fg)'=f'\cdot g'$ for this question and co-incidentally got the correct answer.
Given that $f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x-3}}$ & $g(1)=e$ which of the following options is/are correct?
(a) $g(x)$ is discontinuous at one point.
(b) $\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x)=1$
(c) $\lim_{x\to \alpha} \frac{x^3-8}{x-2}=12$ where $\alpha$ is number of point of discontinuity of $g(x)$
(d) $g(x)$ is discontinuous at two points.

My Solution :
With $f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x-3}}$ , we can see $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=3$ and $f'(x)=\frac{-1}{(x-3)\left(\sqrt{(x-1)(x-3)}\right)}$ so $f'(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=1,3$
Now according to question $f'(x)g'(x)=f(x)g'(x)+g(x)f'(x)$
$\implies g'(x)\left(f'(x)-f(x)\right)=g(x)f'(x)$
$\implies g'(x)\left(\frac{-1}{(x-3)\left(\sqrt{(x-1)(x-3)}\right)}-\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x-3}}\right)=g(x)\left(\frac{-1}{(x-3)\left(\sqrt{(x-1)(x-3)}\right)}\right)$
$\implies g'(x)\left(x^2-4x+4\right)=g(x)$
After solving above differential equation and setting $g(1)=e$ , I am getting
$g(x)=e^{\frac{1}{2-x}}$ which is discontinuous at $x=2$
My Doubt :
(i) Since $f'(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=1,x=3$ so I think $g(x)$ should be discontinuous at $x=3$ too. because We are getting $g(x)$ after solving $f'(x)$
(ii) Is $f'(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=1,3$ correct or should I say it is discontinuous at $x=1$ because $x=3$ is not in domain of $f(x)$

I got $g(x) = (x^2 - 4x + 4)g'(x)$.  Is that my mistake or yours?

@Dan Mine, edited. Thanks.

At least 2 answers are claiming that the Question is somewhat strange : Which textbook has this ?

it's from one of test series (I guess FIITJEE)

I've confirmed that your solution of $g(x)=e^{\frac{1}{2-x}}$ satisfies the differential equation.  $g$ is undefined (vertical asymptote) at $x = 2$, and continuous everywhere else.

(i) Since $f'(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=1$, $x=3$ so I think $g(x)$ should be discontinuous at $x=3$ too. because We are getting $g(x)$ after solving $f'(x)$.

You could make that argument, but note that $f$ isn't just discontinuous at two points: It's undefined for the entire interval $x \in (1, 3]$.  Unless you allow $f(x)$ to be a complex number, in which case $x = 3$ is the only point of discontinuity.
So, I would say that the question is ambiguous, depending on how you interpret the domain of $g$.  There are two points of view you could take:

$g(x)=e^{\frac{1}{2-x}}$ is defined for all $x$ in the expression's natural domain, i.e., $x \ne 2$.
$g(x)$ is defined only for those values where $f$ and $f'$ are both defined, so that the differential equation $f'g + fg' = f'g'$ can be applied.  This excludes $x \in [1, 3]$.

With interpretation #1, $g$ is discontinuous at just one point.  With interpretation #2, $g$ is discontinuous at an infinite number of points.
In either case, statements (c) and (d) are false, since they don't apply to either $\alpha = 1$ or $\alpha = \infty$.  And statement (b) is true, because $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) = e^{0} = 1$.  Statement (a) is ambiguous.

Your view 2 is "almost" what I have in my answer. Even though $f(x)$ is undefined for $x$ values between $1$ & $3$ , that will not automatically make $g(x)$ undefined there : It is just unknown : might be Constant , might be that Exponential , might be some other function , might be undefined !

Posting this to let you know my thought on the matter.
I am not sure whether this is a valid question or not.
Domain & range $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ for $f(x)$ will involve Imaginary Numbers when $x$ is between $1$ & $3$.
Hence we might assume that Domain is $(-\infty,1) \cup [3,+\infty)$
Then "Correct Product Rule" or the "Wrong Product Rule" which Student used is for that Domain.
When we get ODE , it is for that Domain.
Solving it , we will know about $g(x)$ for that Domain.
We have no information about $g(x)$ for $[1,3)$.
We have no information about total number of Points of Discontinuity for $g(x)$.
Hence (a) (c) & (d) are unknown.
With lots of assumptions , we "might" have enough information to know that (b) is true , though that too is not really valid.
My thinking : Question is not meaningful : It is not well-formed.

I think if $f'(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=1,x=3$.You can't just say $g(x)$ should be discontinuous at $x=1,x=3$,because they didn't have direct contact.We can consider a counterexample,$f(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}$＆$g(x)=x$.
